# How do I discuss the morality of fur with a friend?

Tags: friends

I think that fur is terrible and not moral at all, she thinks it's alright. I don't wanna force my opinion down on her, just want to motivate her to do research and maybe think about my views.

We argued about this the last time we have seen each other. She wears fur because she likes the texture and the warmth. I think it's not moral as the killing of animals for fashion and factors that are achieved the same with materials that do not involve the killing of animals is possible.

She thinks that it is alright as she wears leather and eats meat, which I am okay with as her diet requires meat and leather is just a byproduct of meat. She also refuses to investigate and think about it as she is not a very "political" person and rather cares for herself and her environment instead of what is outside of her direct reach.

Comment: You're talking about wearing fur for fashion, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. About wearing it for fashion or just wearing it because people like the warmth and the texture of it

Comment: It may be a good idea to add some context to your question. Like does your friend wear fur, or are they just ok with the idea? Are there any traditional, cultural, or religious factors to consider? How close are you two as friends? And so on.

Comment: First off, she does not care. She eats meat and wears leather which I am fine with as meat is part of her natural diet (I see it as such even as a vegetarian) and leather is just a byproduct of meat. So fur is the same for her. But it isn't for me as it's not the killing for nutrition, but the murder for fashion. Which is why she wears it: fashion. We started off as coworkers, but sometimes do things outside of work and talk all the time at work. There are no cultural or religious factors to consider

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. We can tell you how to broach the subject respectfully or how to ask them not to wear fur around you but we can't give you points to strengthen your argument. What do you want from this question?

Comment: I understand all that. Not trying to judge the morality involved, just saying that adding some details to the question will probably lead to better, more helpful answers.

Comment: @Catjia How to discuss it with bringing her to actually ask herself questions about the morality and to investigate somewhat. But not forcing her to do so.

Comment: _I think that fur is terrible and not moral at all_ - So: You believe that virtually all of humankind was terrible and immoral until PETA came and enlightened us all.... REALLY? _She also refuses to investigate and think about it..  rather cares for herself and her environment instead of what is outside of her direct reach_ | _just want to motivate her to do research and maybe think about my views_-  So you're asking us to help you spread your belief that 99.9% of human-kind is _terrible and immoral_ ...

Comment: _leather is just a byproduct of meat_ - do you actually believe that all leather comes from meat bearing animals? Do you realize that if you slaughter an animal for food, fur will also be a by-product? IMO you might do well to _**do research and maybe think about HER views**_ .

Comment: Asking how to evangelize specific strongly-held positions (i.e. what arguments can you make to her) is off-topic here. If you're asking how in general to broach a conversation where you want to persuade someone to change a behavior, then the specific issue isn't as important as what you have tried already.  If this were more about dialogue and persuasion and less about fur, it would probably do better here.  (Ditto if it were about religion, diet, smoking, guns, immigration, conservatives, liberals...)

Comment: _the murder for fashion_ - Some people like certain foods, some people like certain "fashions". Why is that a problem?

Comment: I won't get into the point of view and whether I agree or not.  I ask these questions of political canvassers and I'll ask you as well, albeit paraphrased.  Are you willing to carefully consider your friend's point of view?  Are you open to changing your beliefs if you do some research?  If the answer is "no", then why should the friend listen to you?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There may be more detail than is listed in your question, but I think you should be able to just talk to your friend about it. A gentle, non-confrontational opening may help a lot (something like, "We obviously have different positions on this. Are you open to talking about it a bit, so that I can better understand where you're coming from?").

And as a general point, your friend may be expecting you to try forcing your opinion on her based on stereotypes or past experiences. It's not totally unreasonable to think that someone who finds your behavior terrible and completely immoral will really be OK with you continuing that behavior, whether meaningful discussions have taken place or not.

Comment: Well, we did have an argument about this once. I think I did this wrong by directly blaming her for it.

Comment: @Juan In that case, I'd expect her to assume that you are trying to force your views on her, whether you really are or not. What was the aftermath of the argument? Do you have some particular reason to think your friend will be more receptive to your arguments this time around?

Comment: I honestly didn't see her since then. That was a few days ago. I think she might be more receptive as my approach would be different. I wouldn't want to blame her, I would just want to motivate her to do research and maybe show her a video of how foxes and martens are produced into fur.

Comment: @JuanNaym You already made an approach. That will permenantly color every conversation you have now. Since you tried to place blame, she will think you are doing the same, no matter how polite or gentle you are in the future. Maybe consider dropping it, or stop being her friend if it matters that much to you?

Comment: @JuanNaym - Why don't you stop playing preacher and just be her friend? And if you believe you have a mission, that comes before friendship - bawl her out and move on. You can't have it both ways.